# iFrame Footer gets cut off when browser shrinks

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

On a website, we have an iframe footer, and so now when the browser shrinks, the footer is cut off. what would be the best way to remedy this?
HTML

```
<div class="footer">
    <iframe src="footer.html" class="footer" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer {
  border: none;
  height: 287.2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom 3;
  width: 100%;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.social {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left:0;
}

.web-footer {
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 100%;
    diplay:block;
  margin: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
  padding: 0;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
  border: 0;
    border-top-color: initial;
    border-top-style: initial;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-right-color: initial;
    border-right-style: initial;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-color: initial;
    border-bottom-style: initial;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-color: initial;
    border-left-style: initial;
    border-left-width: 0px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
}

.footerfull {
  max-width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
  padding: 0;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
  border: 0;
    border-top-color: initial;
    border-top-style: initial;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-right-color: initial;
    border-right-style: initial;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-color: initial;
    border-bottom-style: initial;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-color: initial;
    border-left-style: initial;
    border-left-width: 0px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
}

.footerfullback {
  background: #D2D7D3;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
  padding: 0;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
  border: 0;
    border-top-color: initial;
    border-top-style: initial;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-right-color: initial;
    border-right-style: initial;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-color: initial;
    border-bottom-style: initial;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-color: initial;
    border-left-style: initial;
    border-left-width: 0px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
}

.footwrap {

  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.social>* {
  display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 8px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 8px;
  text-align: center;

}

.social a img{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}



.h5 {
  text-align: center;
      font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.6;
    letter-spacing: 0.070em;
  font-family: Montserrat;
}

.foo {
  width: 100%;
 background:#bdc3c7;
}


.footcontainer {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  min-height: 99%;
}
```

The footer HTML

```
    <div class="footcontainer">
            <footer class="web-footer">
                <div class="footerfull footerfullback">
                    <div class="footwrap">
                        <div class="space"></div>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <ul class="social">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">
                                            <img src="css/social/facebook.png"></img>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="https://twitter.com/">
                                            <img src="css/social/twitter.png"></img>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="https://instagram.com/">
                                            <img src="css/social/Instagram.png"></img>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
                                            <img src="css/social/youtube.png"></img>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="https://plus.google.com/">
                                            <img src="css/social/g+.png"></img>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="https://github.com/" target="_blank">
                                           <img src="css/social/Github.png"></img>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <br/>
                                <a href="https://github.com/[![enter image description here][1]][1]"><p class="h5">Source Code for this Website</p></a>
                                <br/>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                                <div class="foo">
                                        <p class="h5">Thunderbots 2015</p>
                                        <a href="mailto:team@thunderbots.net"><p class="h5">team@thunderbots.net</p></a>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
    </div>
</html>
```

I've tried to look at various website for sticky footers, but it seems like most of the remedies do not work for iframe footers. For our website, it seems too late to go back without iframe footer. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using fixed position instead of absolute? Assuming your `iframe` has the `.footer` class, try this CSS:

```
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 287px;
  border: none;
}
```

PS: decimal pixel amounts will be rounded in CSS, so a height value of `287.2px` should just be `287px`.

Comment: The footer has now just completely disappeared from the website

Comment: Wait sorry, the footer actually scrolls with the page, which is actually kind of a problem, we want the footer to stay at the bottom of the page and not show up until you reach the end.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. If you want the footer to just show up at the end, why not use relative positioning so it's at the end of your content?

Comment: Also, you have the ```.footer``` class on both the container ```<div>``` and the ```<iframe>```. You should only have the above CSS apply to a single element.

Answer (score 0):

Theres no reason a sticky footer wont work in your case, all you need is a fixed height which you have.

```
 height: 287.2px;
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/4Lf35nd3/

Or maybe you have sticky footer and fixed footer confused? a sticky footer is always meant to be at the bottom of content and not go over the to of content whereas a fixed element with "position:fixed" will always stay in the same in reference point its closest parent set to position:relative

Comment: This will not work if the content above the footer is taller than the height of the viewport: http://jsfiddle.net/d7daceho/1/

Comment: Thats what a sticky footer is meant to do, it should never overlap the content above, see http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/ and http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ as examples

Comment: Yeah I think I might have it confused, what I want is for the footer to stay at the bottom of the page, and not appear until you reach the bottom, instead of where the footer moves as your scroll

Comment: Essentially, I want the white space to disappear

Comment: Its sounds like you explaining what the default layout behavior should be i.e without the position: absolute; property, unless you footer html is in a different place in your HTML page and is not directly below your content html.

Comment: I'm confused. If you want the footer to drop to the bottom of the page when there isn't enough content (but otherwise to be pushed down as the content grows beyond the viewport height), then @sjm's solution is correct. If you want the footer to never be "cut off", as you stated in the original question, then my solution with position "fixed" is the ticket. Otherwise, it just sounds like you should keep the default "static" positioning.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses!